# Spring boot : Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and i am creating jar file and deploying on CentOS 7.6.(tomcat 7) The code works perfectly well when running in my intellij IDEA but i am getting below exception when running application on CentOS 7.6

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/dao/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [cn/edu/imau/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'factory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [cn/edu/imau/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myRealm': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activistService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activistServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activistMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activistMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/red/api-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/mapper-1.0.0.jar!/cn/edu/imau/redpioneer/dao/ActivistMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [tk/mybatis/mapper/autoconfigure/MapperAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/alibaba/druid/spring/boot/autoconfigure/DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:258) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at cn.edu.imau.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:17) [classes!/:1.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) [api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [api-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [cn/edu/imau/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'factory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [cn/edu/imau/config/ShiroConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myRealm': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activistService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activistServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'activistMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'activistMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/local/red/api-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/mapper-1.0.0.jar!/cn/edu/imau/redpioneer/dao/ActivistMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [tk/mybatis/mapper/autoconfigure/MapperAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/alibaba/druid/spring/boot/autoconfigure/DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
    <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>beans</module>
        <module>mapper</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.18</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

beans

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
        <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>beans</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- tkMapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tk.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
        <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>mapper</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!--beans-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
            <artifactId>beans</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring-boot-starter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--mybatis starter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--druid starter-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--PageHelper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
            <artifactId>pagehelper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--easyexcel-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>easyexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configurationFile>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/resources/generator/generatorConfig.xml
                    </configurationFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!--mysql-->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.47</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>tk.mybatis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapper</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

common

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
        <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!--beans-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
            <artifactId>beans</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--easyexcel-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>easyexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jwt-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--shiro-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
        <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!--mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--common-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--mail-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
        <artifactId>red-pioneer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <!--service-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.edu.imau</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--web-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--junit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>-->
<!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--            <version>2.4.4</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        &lt;!&ndash;Test&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--            <version>2.4.4</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.9.2</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!--swagger2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--swagger-ui-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xiaoymin</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-bootstrap-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below is my ApiApplication.java

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@MapperScan("cn.edu.imau.redpioneer.dao")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "cn.edu.imau.*")
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

Can anyone let me know why i am getting this error while running my Tomcat.

Comment: Yuor dependencies are a mess, you are mixing at leat 3 versions of Spring Boot (2.4, 2.5 and 2.6) which is a recipe for disasters. For all your Spring Boot Starter dependencies, remove the version attribute.

Comment: Still one time, can't solve

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do not understand